# How to put an hours data label to y axis in range bar chart

Tags: c#, winforms

[Picture : Click > My execute vs desire result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUbe5.png)

I have tired to change the data label of Y-axis from "date" to "timeline" but I don’t know how to do. Suppose the data label of Y-axis can be changed into timeline, I also don't know how to put a code on XY-axis when the chart has changed.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DateTime currentData = DateTime.Now.Date;
    chart1.Series["RUN"].Points.AddXY(1, currentData, currentData.AddDays(5));     
    chart1.Series["WAIT"].Points.AddXY(1, currentData.AddDays(5), currentData.AddDays(10));
    chart1.Series["WAIT"].Points.AddXY(1, currentData.AddDays(10), currentData.AddDays(17));
    chart1.Series["OFF"].Points.AddXY(1, currentData.AddDays(17), currentData.AddDays(30));


    chart1.Series["RUN"].Points[0].AxisLabel = "Machine 1";
    chart1.Series["RUN"]["DrawSideBySide"] = "false";

    chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.Minimum = currentData.AddDays(-1).ToOADate();
    chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.Maximum = currentData.AddDays(28).ToOADate();

     ...
}
```

So, could anyone help me to fullfill the below condition.

I want to make the timeline chart as in a 2nd picture.The information which I want to show in timeline chart are as the following;

1.Y-AXIS : show the labels as an hour following the second picture.

start : 08:00 end 20:00

interval : 1 hour

2. After Y-AXIS were changed as an hours. guild me the code how should it be to ADDXY.

Example

Series["RUN"] put it into 08:35 - 10:45 in machine 1

Series["WAIT"] put it into 10:45 - 12:45 in machine 1

Series["OFF"] put it into 12:45 - 20:00 in machine 1

Comment: which chart component you are using ?

Comment: @karthickj25 Using range bar chart sir. You can see my picture at the top of passage.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by making sure the DateTimes you add all have the same date.  And then by setting a few options on the Y axis.  See below:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  DateTime startTime = DateTime.MinValue.Add(new TimeSpan(8, 25, 0));
  DateTime endTime   = DateTime.MinValue.Add(new TimeSpan(10, 45, 0));
  chart1.Series["RUN"].Points.AddXY(
    1,
    startTime,
    endTime);

  startTime = DateTime.MinValue.Add(new TimeSpan(10, 45, 0));
  endTime = DateTime.MinValue.Add(new TimeSpan(12, 45, 0));
  chart1.Series["WAIT"].Points.AddXY(
    1,
    startTime,
    endTime);

  startTime = DateTime.MinValue.Add(new TimeSpan(12, 45, 0));
  endTime = DateTime.MinValue.Add(new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0));
  chart1.Series["OFF"].Points.AddXY(
    1,
    startTime,
    endTime);


  chart1.Series["RUN"].Points[0].AxisLabel = "Machine 1";
  chart1.Series["RUN"]["DrawSideBySide"] = "false";

  chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.Interval = 60; // Show 1 hour intervals.
  chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Minutes;
  chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm"; // Set the format to show hours and minutes.
}
```

[image: Example chart]

Answer (score -1):

To gunnerone,

Your information is answered for this topic. you are very kindness and helpful. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Sorry for my lately reply.

Comment: This is not an answer, please delete!